# Exit launcher from inside itself in android

Tags: android, launcher

I have created a launcher activity and I want to add there a button that allows the user to exit this launcher and return to the home built in launcher. 
For example, look at [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=marcone.toddlerlock&hl=en). Toddler asks the user to define his activity as launcher, but when the user presses the 4 corners, the home launcher returns to be the current launcher instead of Toddler. I want to do the same - to change the activity state from a launcher activity to a non-launcher activity and backwards.

I can't use something like:

```
finish();
super.onDestroy();
```

in the launcher activity, because it returns to the same activity...

Anyone has an idea of how toddler did it and how can I implement a mechanism that change the activity attributes from a launcher activity to simple activity?

Comment: What does it mean `the launcher that he had in the first place` for you?

Comment: It's very hard to understand your problem. Please use android terms, like "Activity", etc.